# Simulate mouse input in Wine window only

Tags: python, winapi, cursor, wine

I'm trying to write simple autoclicker using win32api.

```
import win32api, win32con
import time
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

for i in xrange(0,4):
    click(255,75)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    click(255,155)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This code works fine under Wine with emulating virtual desktop (generate clicks in proper positions in Wine window) but it takes control of cursor and move it in the wrong places( the same coordinates but in the root window).

How can I make my script take control of cursor only when it is in the Wine window(not always) and to use local(Wine window) coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this would be a script running outside of wine that communicated with the wine script via sockets.